# Build Cling using CMake fails

Tags: software-installation, compiling, cmake

I am trying build Cling (LLVM-based C++ interpreter) on my machine using CMake. I have LLVM and Clang installed. However, I still need to set `CLING_PATH_TO_LLVM_BUILD`. I set it to `/usr/lib/llvm-3.6`, but that didn't work. I want to be able to build it without cloning LLVM. I don't know what to set it to. I have everything installed off of the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to follow https://root.cern.ch/cling-build-instructions - cling still needs a few patches on top of llvm.

Cheers, Axel.

Comment: add important step from link and then add link for more info. only link will not help if link stop working in future then this answer will be useless.